# Why wp_insert_category is not available inside My Custom Page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a simple page template. I want to create category automatically using wp_insert_category but wp_insert_category is not available inside My Custom Page. Any solution?

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: My Custom Page
 * Description: A Page Template with a darker design.
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php 
if (function_exists('wp_insert_category')) {
    echo "This function is available.";
} else {
    echo "This function is not available.";
}
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: include `wp_insert_category` inyour page is the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp_insert_category` is an admin function. You will have to include the taxonomy file first.
Paste the following code in your `functions.php` . then only `wp_insert_category` function will work.

```
if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
        require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
}
```

Comment: I did not have to do this in staging, but I did have to do this in production. There may be a config setting that alleviates this, but I'm not sure what it is.